# Rail 3 UJS complex forms multiple fields_for

Tags: javascript, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-3, ujs

I have a milestone with many tasks. On my project show page, I want to be able to create a milestone with however many tasks the user decides to add to the milestone. How do I add more tasks using

```
milestone_form.fields_for :tasks
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my question with a search for *dynamically* adding forms. And a little help from Ryan's scraps.

https://github.com/alloy/complex-form-examples/blob/a234fde4419836f277d7e340657f1d8418911d68/app/views/projects/_form.html.erb#L40